# Why doesn't clone() allow for this move?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I don't understand why the following doesn't work:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug,Clone,PartialEq)]
struct Foo<'a> {
    contents: HashMap<&'a str, Foo<'a>>,
}

fn bar<'a>(val: Foo<'a>) -> Foo<'a> {
    *val.contents.get("bar").clone().unwrap()
}
```

```rust
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
 --> src/lib.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     *val.contents.get("bar").clone().unwrap()
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Foo<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8ab3c7355903fc34751d5bd5360bb71a

I'm performing a `.clone()`, which I thought should allow me to return the resulting value whose ownership should be disentangled from the input value, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Another weird thing, which isn't a blocker on its own but may hint at the underlying problem, is that for some reason the `.clone()` returns a `&Foo`, which is surprising because in other cases I've mostly seen `.clone()` go from `&T -> T`. This is why the `*` is there; without it this doesn't pass type checking. I know Rust has some "magical" referencing/dereferencing rules, but I can't quite figure this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashMap.get` returns an `Option<&T>`. Cloning this option gives you another `Option<&T>`, referencing the same object.

If you want to convert a `Option<&T>` to a new `Option<T>` where `T` supports `Clone` you can use `.cloned()`. There's also no need to dereference anymore as you have a `T` not an `&T`.

This means your code will look like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1e2194652a932e947025a7b4d38ce2d4):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
struct Foo<'a> {
    contents: HashMap<&'a str, Foo<'a>>,
}

fn bar<'a>(val: Foo<'a>) -> Foo<'a> {
    val.contents.get("bar").cloned().unwrap()
}
```

Comment: I could've sworn I tried that... but you're right, that works.